# Dynamically assign object properties in jQuery/JavaScript to post through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to dynamically have JavaScript object properties to send through ajax.

Here is what I have done:

```
    var checkBoxName = $(this).attr('name');
    var postData = {
        Module: ModuleID,
        Group:GroupID
    };
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        postData.checkBoxName = 1;
    }else{
        postData.checkBoxName = 0;
    }
    $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>user_site/user_group_add_pri/updatePrivilege",
        data:postData,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (output) {
            console.log(output);
        }
```

I have multiple checkboxes. every checkbox has different name so what I am trying to do is post data to controller with checkbox name and its value.

But instead it is sending checkBoxName for all checkboxes.

I mean `CheckBoxName` is a variable but I used it like this because I thought it would send its value but it is not sending.

I tried like this `postData.checkBoxName =` but instead of value of variable it is sending as Text?

---

### Update

The event Occurs when checkbox value is changed.

```
        $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change',function(e){

///Above Code Inside Here
}
```

Comment: What is the context of `$(this)` and can we see the event binding

Comment: `postData[checkBoxName] = ...`

Comment: You don't assign `checkBoxName` as part of `postData`, you're assigning the *value* (1 or 0) to the `checkBoxName` field.

Comment: @haim770
How to the checkbox name dynamically as the property of the object??

Comment: Use @thebjorn's solution

Comment: @thebjorn
Tried your way, i got this error.
`SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
 

postData.[checkBoxName] = 1;`

Comment: @SizzlingCode see my comment above for how to do it dynamically... (it's basic Javascript).

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you that there is no `.` between `postData` and `[`.

Comment: @thebjorn
yes i have tried your way even tried with concatanation, but getting error missin name after .operator??

Comment: if your checkbox name like **mycheckbox.name** you will get the error, you should parse it.

Comment: @thebjorn
OMG, i was using `.` dot in between.. Many Many Thanks.. xD.. you are awesome.. removed the extra dot its working now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, I might have an idea.

You can do a loop through all your checkboxes and check if they are checked or not. Then push it into a tab and send through ajax :

```
var infoCb = new Array();
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    var tempArray = {
        'nameOfCb' : $(this).attr('name'),
        'value' : $(this).attr('checked')
    }
    infoCb.push(tempArray);
});
```

And then send it via Ajax.

Comment: because he wants to have all checkboxes ,checked or not, no ?? If you use $(':checkbox:checked') you'll only have the one checked. But I might have misunderstood.